# mocking a method with an anonymous type argument

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, tdd, moq

I have the following code:

```
var connector = new Mock<IConector>();

connector
    .Setup(cn => cn.listar("FetchEstandar", new Estandar(), new {Id = 1}))
    .Returns(new List<Estandar>{ new Estandar {Id = 1} });

 var entidad = connector.Object
     .listar("FetchEstandar", new Estandar(), new {Id = 1});
```

when I call `listar` on the connector Object, I get an `"Expression Cannot Contain an Anonymouse Type"` error. I've tried with rhino mocks and moq.

Is there any way I can mock this method? am I doing something wrong? alternatively, I could ignore this parameter but I don't know how. I really just need to test the value of the first parameter and ignorearguments works but I have no idea whether or how I can get this value if I use it

Comment: Can you please post your `IConector.listar` method signature? Which moq version are you using? Because the version 3.1.416.3 doesn't throw any error when I execute your code.

Comment: Moq 4.0.10827.0 is not throwing any errors either if I use 'IEnumerable<Estandar> listar(string name, Estandar estandar, object id);'  as the signature for listar, however the setup will never match because the new Estandar() in the setup is not the same as the new Estandar when called.

Comment: yeah, sorry, it does work but returns an empty list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know if this is the only way to match an anonymous object but it can be done using It.Is<>() and reflection

```
public class Estandar {
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public interface IConector {
    IEnumerable<Estandar> listar(string name, Estandar estandar, object key);   
}


[TestMethod]
public void CheckAnonymous() {

    var connector = new Mock<IConector>();

    connector.Setup(cn => cn.listar("FetchEstandar",
                                    It.IsAny<Estandar>(),
                                    It.Is<object>(it => MatchKey(it, 1))))
             .Returns(new List<Estandar> { new Estandar { Id = 1 } });

    var entidad = connector.Object.listar("FetchEstandar", new Estandar(), new { Id = 1 });

    Assert.AreEqual(1, entidad.Count());

}

public static bool MatchKey(object key, int soughtId) {
    var ret = false;
    var prop = key.GetType().GetProperty("Id");
    if (prop != null) {
        var id = (int)prop.GetValue(key, null);
        ret = id == soughtId;
    }
    return  ret;
}
```